# editor window shows whole path, i would prefer only the file name

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to change the name of a windwo of *.m files, that it just shows the file name?
At the moment it shows the whole path and it makes switching between the different editor windows very annoying, since the title is shortened (when you press [alt]+[tab]) and the same for every window...

Comment: Why don't you tab all your opened m files in the same window?

Comment: yes, that's aso good!